# Can PHP Array Keys have an Alias?

Tags: php, arrays, alias

This is just a curious question, the reasoning behind it is purely to be slightly more lazy on my part. Here is what I mean..

Say I have a website, where htaccess makes nice urls, and sends that data to the $_GET['p'] array key as the current 'page'. In the index file, I setup the page, and the first thing I do is setup some page settings in a config file, $_PAGE array. Now, say I have multiple pages I want to have the same settings, (and down in the page, other things may slightly change that do not correspond to the settings. So currently, I have something that looks like the following 2 php files.

```
// index.php
include('page.array.php');

echo '<title>'.$_PAGE[$_GET['p']]['title'].'</title>';

// page.array.php
$_PAGE = array(
    'some/page/' => array(
        'title' => 'This is an example'
    )
)
$_PAGE['some/aliased/page/'] = $_PAGE['some/page/'];
```

Notice that at the end ofthe page array, in order to 'alias' a page I must add this to the end after the array has been created.

Is there any method in php that maybe I am just unaware of, that could make me a tad bit lazier (and at the same time add to cleaner code), and make it so I can simply alias the key? I notice the following doesn't work, and I suppose my question is, is there any way to create the alias within the same array during the creation of the array?

This example deosn't work:

```
// page.array.php
$_PAGE = array(
    'some/page/' => array(
        'title' => 'This is an example'
    ),
    'some/aliased/page/' => $_PAGE['some/page/']
)
```

Maybe a way to refer to "this" array, from within itself?

If this is not possible, I don't have an issue with the "Not Possible" answer. Though if you have a better method of solving this, other then the way I have described above, in the sake of being lazier, I would be interested in reading it :)

Comment: Short answer, no, not during the creation of it unfortunately. Later on yes, like you do, or even with references (so changes are reflected), but the 'source' has to exist & be fully instantiated before that can happen. I don't mind seeing those aliasses added on the end though, there's something to say for it to distinguish 'real' pages & aliasses.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can have array values that mirror other values in the array like this. The first thing that comes to mind though would be for you to construct your `$_PAGE` array from within a `switch` statement, using fall-through values as aliases:

```php
// Define path for testing, and empty page array
$path = "some/aliased/page";
$page = Array();

// Time to evaluate our path
switch ($path) {
    // If it's either of these two cases
    case "some/page":
    case "some/aliased/page":
        // Assign this array to $page
        $page = Array("Title" => "Two Paths, One Page.");
        break;
    // If it's this case
    case "some/other/path":
        // Assign this array to $page
        $page = Array("Title" => "Something else.");
        break;
    // If the path isn't found, default data
    default:
        $page = Array("Title" => "Page not found");
}

// Output the result
var_dump($page);
```

Execute it: [http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions...ebd3dee1f37c5612c25](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c86b962dd84a4148e0b4cebd3dee1f37c5612c25)

Comment: I should have mentioned in my post, that this was the original way of doing this. The issue comes down to the amount of pages on this 1 site, a switch statement becomes large and ugly after some time, and where I have my page array, is in a config file at the top of the ordeal, this allowing me to make any changes (if I need to) to the array before making it to where all the page's sets are actually going.. Anyway, I appreciate your respond, wish I could do a fall-through type of deal in an array ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible:

```
$_PAGE = array('some/page/' => array('title' => 'This is an example'));
$_PAGE['some/aliased/page/'] = &$_PAGE['some/page/'];
$_PAGE['some/page/'] = 7;
var_dump($_PAGE);
```

Use the & to get a reference to a (non-object) variable instead of its value.

Comment: I don't need to reference the actual array, I need to alias it, so that the certain pages start with the same settings as another. Those alias'd pages do sometimes change the settings very slightly before they are used. The issue is, I don't want to create 6 million arrays that are identical except for a small changes. Currently, I setup "alias'd" key's through this manner, minus the referencing, I am just wanting be lazy and say move that aliased or "referenced" key directly into the array initialization, so I don't have to scroll all the way to the bottom of the page each time heh.

Comment: still not getting what the actual issue is